# Git with Visual Studio - duplicate folder/filename with only different capitalization?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

### Commits and Capitalization and Duplicate Files - Oh My!

My son is working through the [SuperAdventure C# Tutorial](http://scottlilly.com/learn-c-by-building-a-simple-rpg-index/) and I've got him committing to a local Git repo, and pushing to a [Github repo](https://github.com/TheDoctor33/ldl-SuperAdventure-cs-tutorial).  Somewhere along the way, he ended up with some strange errors in his repo that would alternate changes to a particular file every other commit, and sometimes show the same changes to both of the following filenames:

```
 SuperAdventure/SuperAdvetnure.cs
 superadventure/superadvetnure.cs
```

(And yes - he spelled it wrong on the *.cs file).  The kicker is that there is only one file (the capitalized, original version).  Git seems to sometimes think that the changes are in one or the other, or even both of these files, and after committing the changes Git thinks are there, then it just sees the inverse of the changes that were just committed (i.e. the lines that were added are now removed and vice versa).

If I look at the history of each commit in Git Extensions, looking at the File Tree tab, I can see that starting at commit 698f378a (Lesson 16.1-refactoring), the File Tree shows the addition of the uncapitalized `superadventure/superadvetnure.cs` file, in addition to the capitalized original, and this folder and file exist in every future commit.  The `superadventure` folder doesn't have any other files in it - no other file in the `SuperAdventure` folder is ghost-duplicated, just the one.

---

### So, what is the deal here?

Since windows doesn't care about capitalization - but Unix does, is there is some strange interaction between Git and Windows or Git and Visual Studio? I have no idea how he managed to get the different capitalization into the Git repo in the first place.  The problem seems to be that when Git tries to put both of these files into the working directory, they just overwrite each other.

I've tried some cherry-picking and rebasing and get the weird errors described above - but that was before I found the origin commit that added the ghost file duplicate - maybe starting with the commit before that, rebasing would work?

Is there a way to directly remove the duplicate file?  I suppose this could mess up some of the follow-on commits?

---

### The Question

**What is the best way to fix this and remove the duplicated `superadventure/superadvetnure.cs` folder and file?**

**Bonus Question:** How could this have happened in the first place?

Comment: FYI - a few weeks later, this happened to him again with a different file: `Engine/Player.cs`, which had a ghost of `engine/player.cs`, while working from the same PC (his laptop).  I wonder if the root cause could be related to something on his PC, like a custom harddrive or memory driver?  Laptops often end up with custom hardware and drivers.  In this particular case, it is an Asus with dual video cards (the second is a 960m and has a funny setup).

Comment: *What worked for me:* renaming the existing file, then committing changes which leads to deleting a ghost file. Then ***renaming*** back and ***committing*** changes once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with [max630's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46249679/6501141), I was able to successfully fix this repo issue locally (not directly on Github as he suggested).  I didn't want to fix it in Github, because I was concerned about side-effects from directly deleting the offending ghost file in a commit on Github.

As I ran through the process I found that my concern was likely justified - after removing the ghost file from some commits during rebasing there ended up being at least one follow-on commit that had no changes.  I'm not sure what that would have done if I had deleted the file in Github.

---

## Update 2019 - Much easier process to fix bad cases from Git in Windows (and why it happens):

I've run into this problem subsequently, it happens anytime you change case in Windows, then commit to the same repo. The repo will NOT change the case. But it's way simpler to fix than I mention below.

The below is for just a single filename with the wrong case. If the process is done twice, it should fix an issue like from the original question above (just much easier).

You can just commit with the file removed from the repo (commit a deletion of the file), then commit again with the file back in the working directory, with the final case you want. However, after the first commit, rather than make a second commit, you can just amend the first commit, which avoids having to make 2 separate commits.

Here are the steps for a single wrong case fix - apologize for not having all of the exact command-line Git commands - I use a GUI. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

1. Rename the file (i.e. from `filename` to `temp_filename`) with the final case desired.
2. In your working directory, git will show both a deletion of `filename` and the addition of `temp_filename`. Do not stage both changes to the index. Only stage the deletion for the old filename to the index (something like 'git add filename')
3. Commit. If you haven't pushed the last commit yet, you can just amend the last commit to avoid making a new commit just to fix the case, if desired.
4. Rename `temp_filename` back to just `filename`. Add `filename` to the index (`git add filename`), make sure the capitalization is what you want, and amend the last commit.

Note: If you are okay rewriting history, you can just amend the current commit twice in a row to have the same effect, and not have to make any new commits. You shouldn't do that if you have pushed the latest commit. Should probably mention the rename in the amended commit message, as Git will NOT show anything in diff about the change.

#### Why it happens

Git appears to be ignoring case when deciding if the file exists, and therefore doesn't see any difference between filenames with different case. That's valid, but the issue is that Git stores the file internally with the case intact. Also valid. The problem is that if the case changes, Git doesn't notice and refuses to update the filename in the Git tree object.

However, if you delete the file from the repo, then Git has to add the filename to a tree object fresh again, and it always takes the current case when it does that, so if the file is deleted, then adding it back again will capture the new case.

---

#### Answer from 2017

Here is the process that worked for me:

1. Use Git Extensions Git GUI to look at the "File Tree" for each commit. Go backward in history until you find the earliest commit that doesn't have the issue.
2. Create a new branch with a name like `fixedmaster`, etc. at that last good commit.
3. **Replay the commits from the master branch onto the new fixedmaster branch, ensuring the ghost file is not a part of each commit.**

   - I did this using `git cherry-pick <commit>` with `fixedmaster` checked out (actually I did it with Git Extensions GUI option for Cherry Pick).
   - **After the cherry-pick, but before committing, do a `git status` and see if the ghost file is included. When it was one of the changes, or showed up as an added or deleted file, I was able to clear it out of index with `git reset HEAD <filename>` (in my case, filename was `superadventure/superadvetnure.cs`), and that actually caused it to disappear completely (makes sense: the ghost doesn't really exist..)**
   - Make the commit - you can use `git commit --amend` to alter the existing commit from the cherry-pick, or can make a brand new one.
   - **NOTE:** There is probably a way to do an interactive rebase of all commits from there to the current master branch commit, but I had issues making this work right and getting lost along the way.  Part of the problem was that once the issue was removed, some of the commits had no changes in them anymore (they ended up being "ghost" commits!).
   - **EDIT:** after fixing it on my PC, I helped him fix it on his (for him to learn more Git, of course!). There were a few times after cherry-picking that it had some files in the Index, and some unstaged - usually this meant a ghost file was involved. We fixed it by unstaging all files from the index, which would eliminate the ghost, then adding them back in again, which captured just the real changes.
4. Once this process is complete for `fixedmaster`, you would need to do the same for any other branches.
5. You can switch `master` over to `fixedmaster`, but consider a few things first:

   - Let all users know about the issue somehow. If they are developing new fixes, they need to wait to fetch the new branches and start working on those instead. When you swap to the new branches you can make things very messy for them.  You may actually want to transition from the old to new master in stages.
   - To keep the old branches, I'd recommend putting a tag at the end of every branch before moving over to the new ones - the tag will keep the broken branch until you are sure the new ones are working (or permanently, if desired).  It will not be garbage-collected with a tag there. Tags are preferable to creating a branch there permanently, especially since you don't want anyone to add commits to them.
6. You can reset `master` to the new `fixedmaster`

   - Checkout master
   - Create a tag of `oldmaster` or similar.
   - Reset --hard to `fixedmaster` commit
   - Delete branch `fixedmaster`
   - Now `master` should be at the location of the fixed branch, with the old master branch present, and tagged at the end. If you want to get rid of it in the future, just delete the tag.
7. Repeat for other branches, if needed
8. Force push master (and any other fixed branches) up to the remote repo.  Of course, this can cause havok if you have lots of users that aren't aware this is going to happen, as discussed above.

There are other ways to go about the finer details, but you get the picture.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can remove it. Best to do it in github interface, no that there is no risk that git recognize deletion of wrong file. It make sense to clone again after that.

Bonus answer: it's hard to say unless you provide version of VS, git, which interface you were using etc. and try to reproduce it.

Just some points:

- Git is case-aware in its core, but in Windows port(s) there are tricks which try to make it work at case-insensitive filsystem. They can have issues and improve over time
- It is known that VS sometimes "loses" case of opened files, and show them as lowercase. I have seen it myself and I seem to have seen it discussed here.
- VS before 2017 used to use not the official port but alternative library (libgit2), maybe there waere some issues there.

I'd recommend to install VS 2017 and latest git version (or is it bundled with VS?) and watch if it happens again.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Now to find out what breaks when I start removing the files (i.e. how many of those commits saved the changes to the lower-case version...).  Oh well, we'll keep a copy of the messed up repo as a backup.  **Note on Versions, etc.:** My son was using 2017 Community version of VS, and a version of Git does come bundled (shouldn't be too old, right?).  I can't go check exactly which version he had, because he had some issues getting Git Extensions installed, and I had him reinstall the latest Git as well (2.14 or so?).